# Passing variables to mixin in LESS

Tags: css, less, mixins

I'm fairly new to LESS and mixins but i'm trying to generate a mixin to dynamicly generate some classes with certain variables. The mixin below is not working properly. Could anyone point me in the right direction please ?

```css
@colors: primary, secondary, succes, info, warning, danger;

.create-inbox(@index) when (@index > 0) {
    @color: extract(@colors, @index);

    .inbox-@{color}-lighten {
        --var-inbox-color: var(--var-@{color});
        background-color: var(--var-@{color}-bg-subtle); // Doesn't work from this point on

        &[href] {
            color: var(--var-@{color});
            text-decoration: none;
            background-color: var(--var-@{color}-bg-subtle);

            &:is(:hover, :focus) {
                color: var(--var-@{color});
                text-decoration: none;
                background-color: var(--var-@{color}-bg-subtle)
            }
        }
    }

    .create-inbox(@index - 1);
}

.create-inbox(length(@colors));
```

The wished result is as followed:

```
.inbox-primary-lighten {
    --var-inbox-color: var(--var-primary);
    background-color: var(--var-primary-bg-subtle)
}

.inbox-primary-lighten[href] {
    color: var(--var-primary);
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: var(--var-primary-bg-subtle)
}

.inbox-primary-lighten[href]:is(:hover, :focus) {
    color: var(--var-primary);
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: var(--var-primary-bg-subtle)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider [escaping](https://lesscss.org/#escaping) the `var()` values that are using variable interpolation:

```less
@colors: primary, secondary, succes, info, warning, danger;

.create-inbox(@index) when (@index > 0) {
    @color: extract(@colors, @index);

    .inbox-@{color}-lighten {
        --var-inbox-color: var(--var-@{color});
        background-color: var(~"--var-@{color}-bg-subtle");

        &[href] {
            color: var(~"--var-@{color}");
            text-decoration: none;
            background-color: var(~"--var-@{color}-bg-subtle");

            &:is(:hover, :focus) {
                color: var(~"--var-@{color}");
                text-decoration: none;
                background-color: var(~"--var-@{color}-bg-subtle")
            }
        }
    }

    .create-inbox(@index - 1);
}

.create-inbox(length(@colors));
```

See it working in [this Less Preview](https://lesscss.org/less-preview/#eyJjb2RlIjoiQGNvbG9yczogcHJpbWFyeSwgc2Vjb25kYXJ5LCBzdWNjZXMsIGluZm8sIHdhcm5pbmcsIGRhbmdlcjtcblxuLmNyZWF0ZS1pbmJveChAaW5kZXgpIHdoZW4gKEBpbmRleCA+IDApIHtcbiAgICBAY29sb3I6IGV4dHJhY3QoQGNvbG9ycywgQGluZGV4KTtcblxuICAgIC5pbmJveC1Ae2NvbG9yfS1saWdodGVuIHtcbiAgICAgICAgLS12YXItaW5ib3gtY29sb3I6IHZhcigtLXZhci1Ae2NvbG9yfSk7XG4gICAgICAgIGJhY2tncm91bmQtY29sb3I6IHZhcih+XCItLXZhci1Ae2NvbG9yfS1iZy1zdWJ0bGVcIik7XG5cbiAgICAgICAgJltocmVmXSB7XG4gICAgICAgICAgICBjb2xvcjogdmFyKH5cIi0tdmFyLUB7Y29sb3J9XCIpO1xuICAgICAgICAgICAgdGV4dC1kZWNvcmF0aW9uOiBub25lO1xuICAgICAgICAgICAgYmFja2dyb3VuZC1jb2xvcjogdmFyKH5cIi0tdmFyLUB7Y29sb3J9LWJnLXN1YnRsZVwiKTtcblxuICAgICAgICAgICAgJjppcyg6aG92ZXIsIDpmb2N1cykge1xuICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIGNvbG9yOiB2YXIoflwiLS12YXItQHtjb2xvcn1cIik7XG4gICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgdGV4dC1kZWNvcmF0aW9uOiBub25lO1xuICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIGJhY2tncm91bmQtY29sb3I6IHZhcih+XCItLXZhci1Ae2NvbG9yfS1iZy1zdWJ0bGVcIilcbiAgICAgICAgICAgIH1cbiAgICAgICAgfVxuICAgIH1cblxuICAgIC5jcmVhdGUtaW5ib3goQGluZGV4IC0gMSk7XG59XG5cbi5jcmVhdGUtaW5ib3gobGVuZ3RoKEBjb2xvcnMpKTsiLCJhY3RpdmVWZXJzaW9uIjoiNC4xLjMifQ==).